# What happens to docker service configs or secrets if a swarm is completely stopped?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm aware that service configs and secrets are stored in the RAFT log and that this log is replicated to other swarm managers.. but what if the entire swarm is stopped? Is the RAFT log persistent or should you always keep local copies?

Comment: I did it just now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54052419/how-to-get-secrets-from-broken-docker-swarm/54052869#54052869

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found out that if you back up the swarm, you should be able to recover as detailed in the documentation:

> Back up the swarm
>   Docker manager nodes store the swarm state and manager logs in the /var/lib/docker/swarm/ directory. In 1.13 and higher, this data includes the keys used to encrypt the Raft logs. Without these keys, you will not be able to restore the swarm.
>
> You can back up the swarm using any manager. Use the following procedure.
>
> > If the swarm has auto-lock enabled, you will need the unlock key in order to restore the swarm from backup. Retrieve the unlock key if necessary and store it in a safe location. If you are unsure, read Lock your swarm to protect its encryption key.
> >
> > Stop Docker on the manager before backing up the data, so that no data is being changed during the backup. It is possible to take a backup while the manager is running (a “hot” backup), but this is not recommended and your results will be less predictable when restoring. While the manager is down, other nodes will continue generating swarm data that will not be part of this backup.
> >
> > Note: Be sure to maintain the quorum of swarm managers. During the time that a manager is shut down, your swarm is more vulnerable to losing the quorum if further nodes are lost. The number of managers you run is a trade-off. If you regularly take down managers to do backups, consider running a 5-manager swarm, so that you can lose an additional manager while the backup is running, without disrupting your services.
> >     Back up the entire /var/lib/docker/swarm directory.
> >
> > Restart the manager.